# The Eternal File.Exist CLR C# not working when called from SQL Server but working in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using a CLR to verify if a file exists using C# method. I've created an assembly and function in sql server and I'm Passing a parameter.

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class FileExist
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static bool fn_FileExistCLR(string FilePath){     

     return System.IO.File.Exists(FilePath);                
  }
}
```

i've created the assembly in sql server:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY FileExistCLR2
FROM 'C:\MSSQLTips\FileExist2.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS
```

I've Created the function also:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fc_ChkFlCLR2](@filename [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS nvarchar(4000) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
     EXTERNAL NAME [FileExistCLR2].[FileExist].[fn_FileExistCLR] 
GO
```

A parameter is being passed by the function to the CLR.

```
declare @filevar as nvarchar(4000)
set @filevar = ltrim(rtrim('T:\\Project\\XML_ErrorFile20131106.txt'))
--set @filevar = ltrim(rtrim('C:\QA_Ticket.xls'))
SELECT [PlayNet].[dbo].[fc_ChkFlCLRChk] (@filevar)   
GO
```

Local file is being found but not for the file in the network folder:

Result 1 - if file is in a network folder, function returns false
Result 2 - if file is in a local folder, function returns TRUE.

I'm running these in a local sql server and tried adding @ also but to no avail.

To cross check. I've created a C# method that outputs the result in the command line. Curiously, the same file in the network is being detected by file.exist. Please Help

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class FileExist
{
   // [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    static void Main()
        {
        string FilePath = "T:\\Project\\XML_ErrorFile20131106.txt";
        string retFilePath;
            if (File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                 retFilePath = "True";
                 Console.WriteLine(retFilePath);
                    Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else 
                retFilePath = "false";
                Console.WriteLine(retFilePath);
                    Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely that the user that the SQL Server process is running as does not have a T drive. It would be much better (and safer) to use UNC drive notation for this type of work (i.e. `\\thefileshare\project\xml...txt`).

Comment: +1. also SQL's user may (or rather should not) have access to shares altogether...

Comment: Thanks Guys. I've used UNC also and didn't work. What I didn't do is try it on a different shared network folder which is the one I will use eventually. :D And it Worked!!!